# sql self join problems how to find the duplicates from same table

Tags: sql, join, self

I am student and

I have such kind of a table structures

```
student (sid, sname, gender, age, year, gpa)
```

---

```
dept(dname, numphds)
```

---

```
course(cno, cname, dname)
```

---

```
enroll(sid, grade, dname, cno, sectno)
```

and i want the results for.....

Q-Print the names of students who are taking both a "Computer Sciences" course and a "Maths" course................

I have tried following query but it does not give me throughput..............

```
select e.sid, s.sname  from 
    enroll e ,enroll e1 ,student s ,course c 
    where s.sid=e.sid, 
         e.cno =c.cno 
      and e.sid=e1.sid 
    and c.cname='computer science' and c.name='maths';
```

Comment: dear there is no self join in it you can use inner join or outer join if you need example then i will send it

Comment: @unseendreamzzz ---- yes sure....it will be helpfull for me i got stuck here....

Comment: ok dear just post you script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been more than 20 years since proper joins were introduced to SQL. FFS use them!

Try this:

```
select s.sid, s.sname
from student s
join enroll e on e.sid = s.sid
join course c on c.cno = e.cno and c.cname='computer science'
join enroll e1 on e1.sid = s.sid
join course c1 on c1.cno = e1.cno and c1.name='maths'
```

Note how you may put non-key conditions in a join condition. Although the query would still work if the course names were in a `where` clause, putting the conditions in the join clause makes it more obvious where they apply, which improves readability.

By formatting well and ordering the tables sanely, you can actually read the query and (hopefully) understand it.

Comment: you only joined to `course` once, and you put two conditions on it, which together could never be true: the course name can not be both 'maths' and 'computer science'. You could have tried an OR, but then you'd have to group using a `having count(c.id) > 1` to enforce that *both* conditions were found and the query would have been ugly. Although this is very slightly less efficient (so small, it would be hard to measure), it's way more readable IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

use the following code

```
select e.said, s.sname from enroll e inner join 
enrool e1 on e1.sid = e.sid inner join
student s on s.sid = e.sid inner join
course c on c.cno = e.cno
where c.cname = 'computer science' and c.name = 'maths'
```

if you need to use the left join then use

```
    select e.said, s.sname from enroll e left join 
enrool e1 on e1.sid = e.sid left join
student s on s.sid = e.sid left join
course c on c.cno = e.cno
where c.cname = 'computer science' and c.name = 'maths'
```

Comment: @unseendreamzzz.....your answer is also currect but it is repetating the resultset multiple times i think we should use distinct to avoid it......thank you.

Comment: dear you just mention the join thats way

Comment: i send you the 2 answer

Comment: but its ok dear it solve your problem it make me happy dear :D